# "Unexpected token 'export' " happening while using react-dnd package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am creating a drag and drop list using react-dnd package and it is giving me the below error while compiling.

```
Error in /turbo_modules/dnd-core@16.0.1/dist/actions/dragDrop/beginDrag.js (4:21)
Unexpected token 'export'
```

Here are the files i am using,

**DraggableItem.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd';

interface DraggableItemProps {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}

export const DraggableItem: React.FC<DraggableItemProps> = ({ id, text }) => {
  const [, ref] = useDrag({
    type: 'ITEM',
    item: { id },
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={itemStyles}>
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

const itemStyles: React.CSSProperties = {
  padding: '8px',
  border: '1px solid #ccc',
  marginBottom: '4px',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  cursor: 'move',
};
```

**DroppableList.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import DraggableItem from './DraggableItem';

interface Item {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}

export const DroppableList: React.FC = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([
    { id: 1, text: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Item 3' },
  ]);

  const handleDrop = (id: number) => {
    const draggedItem = items.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (draggedItem) {
      const updatedItems = items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      setItems([...updatedItems, draggedItem]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <div style={listStyles}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <DraggableItem key={item.id} id={item.id} text={item.text} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div style={listStyles}>
        <h3>Drop items here:</h3>
        <div
          onDrop={() => handleDrop(1)}
          onDragOver={allowDrop}
          style={droppableStyles}
        >
          Drop Zone 1
        </div>
        <div
          onDrop={() => handleDrop(2)}
          onDragOver={allowDrop}
          style={droppableStyles}
        >
          Drop Zone 2
        </div>
        <div
          onDrop={() => handleDrop(3)}
          onDragOver={allowDrop}
          style={droppableStyles}
        >
          Drop Zone 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </DndProvider>
  );
};

const listStyles: React.CSSProperties = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignItems: 'center',
};

const droppableStyles: React.CSSProperties = {
  border: '2px dashed #ccc',
  padding: '16px',
  margin: '8px',
  width: '150px',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

function allowDrop(event: React.DragEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import DroppableList from './DroppableList';
import './style.css';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DroppableList />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the link to the sandbox i created using this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dfg3ek?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FDraggableItem.tsx,src%2FDroppableList.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Findex.tsx&title=React%20Starter

Any kind of insight will be appreciated